# gomobile init fails to find stdlib.h

Tags: go, gomobile

I'm trying to make a cross-platform native library using go and found [this](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Mobile) tutorial for gomobile. However, when I try to initialize it (even if I give the Android NDK path although I don't in the example below) it seems to fail because it can't find `stdlib.h`.

I tried to do some investigation around cgo but nothing jumped out at me, was hoping someone more familiar with the ecosystem could point me in the right direction.

```
$ gomobile init
gomobile: go install -gcflags=-shared -ldflags=-shared -pkgdir=/Users/myusername/go/pkg/gomobile/pkg_android_arm std failed: exit status 2
# runtime/cgo
_cgo_export.c:2:10: fatal error: 'stdlib.h' file not found
```

My environment... (I'm on OS X El Capitan with fresh install of go1.9 darwin/amd64)

```
$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/myusername/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/rx/l7pzlrld2mqczrfb36t536hh0000gp/T/go-build735124167=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
```

**EDIT:** (Adding verbose output of failed init)

```
$ gomobile init -v

# Installing golang.org/x/mobile/gl.

# Installing golang.org/x/mobile/app.

# Installing golang.org/x/mobile/exp/app/debug.

# Installing std for android/arm.
runtime/internal/sys
runtime/internal/atomic
runtime
sync/atomic
unicode
internal/race
errors
unicode/utf8
math
math/bits
container/list
container/ring
crypto/subtle
crypto/internal/cipherhw
internal/nettrace
runtime/cgo
vendor/golang_org/x/crypto/poly1305
sync
encoding
unicode/utf16
image/color
internal/cpu
internal/syscall/windows
internal/syscall/windows/registry
image/color/palette
internal/syscall/windows/sysdll
io
syscall
internal/singleflight
runtime/race
# runtime/cgo
_cgo_export.c:2:10: fatal error: 'stdlib.h' file not found
vendor/golang_org/x/text/secure
vendor/golang_org/x/text/unicode
bytes
strings
hash
crypto/cipher
runtime/trace
hash/crc32
hash/adler32
crypto/hmac
hash/crc64
hash/fnv
vendor/golang_org/x/text/transform
text/tabwriter
bufio
path
html
strconv
math/rand
math/cmplx
time
internal/syscall/unix
reflect
crypto/aes
crypto
crypto/rc4
encoding/base64
encoding/base32
encoding/ascii85
crypto/sha512
crypto/md5
crypto/sha1
crypto/sha256
image
internal/poll
image/internal/imageutil
image/draw
image/jpeg
os
os/signal
fmt
sort
encoding/binary
path/filepath
compress/bzip2
encoding/pem
container/heap
regexp/syntax
runtime/debug
crypto/des
vendor/golang_org/x/crypto/chacha20poly1305/internal/chacha20
vendor/golang_org/x/crypto/curve25519
vendor/golang_org/x/crypto/chacha20poly1305
io/ioutil
compress/flate
context
archive/tar
math/big
compress/lzw
encoding/hex
debug/dwarf
debug/gosym
debug/plan9obj
database/sql/driver
encoding/csv
encoding/gob
encoding/json
database/sql
encoding/xml
archive/zip
compress/gzip
compress/zlib
debug/macho
debug/elf
debug/pe
log
vendor/golang_org/x/net/http2/hpack
vendor/golang_org/x/text/unicode/bidi
vendor/golang_org/x/text/unicode/norm
net/url
mime
mime/quotedprintable
net/http/internal
flag
crypto/dsa
crypto/elliptic
encoding/asn1
crypto/rand
go/token
go/scanner
crypto/rsa
vendor/golang_org/x/text/secure/bidirule
regexp
text/template/parse
go/ast
go/constant
os/exec
text/scanner
crypto/ecdsa
crypto/x509/pkix
image/gif
image/png
vendor/golang_org/x/net/idna
index/suffixarray
testing
internal/trace
runtime/pprof
text/template
net/internal/socktest
os/user
runtime/pprof/internal/profile
testing/iotest
testing/quick
go/parser
go/printer
testing/internal/testdeps
internal/testenv
go/doc
html/template
go/types
go/format
go/build
go/internal/gccgoimporter
go/internal/gcimporter
go/internal/srcimporter
go/importer
gomobile: go install -gcflags=-shared -ldflags=-shared -pkgdir=/Users/myusername/go/pkg/gomobile/pkg_android_arm -v std failed: exit status 2
```

Comment: Have you installed the xcode commandline tools?

Comment: Yes and reset the path for them as well (didn't change the path, must have already been using default), if there is a config issue with them it must be something beyond that...

Comment: kind of confounding... if i run `go install -gcflags=-shared -ldflags=-shared -pkgdir=/Users/myusername/go/pkg/gomobile/pkg_android_arm std` on its own it succeeds, just doesnt work when gomobile tries to run it i guess? (which means init is still broken for me...)

Comment: Tried with Go 1.8 and experiencing same issue

Comment: This may be you, but an issue has been opened; https://github.com/golang/go/issues/21802. Based on the issue appears to have been a change in the NDK.

Comment: i didnt file but yesterday was looking for such an issue. seems highly likely to be same issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was still reproduced on `go1.10 darwin/amd64` even with [issue21802](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/21802) patched.

If `go install -gcflags=-shared -ldflags=-shared -pkgdir=/Users/myusername/go/pkg/gomobile/pkg_android_arm std` can be run on its own it succeeds, assuming the problem is an Runtime ENV problem, there is a workaround.

The trick to solve this problem:

1.Run `go install -gcflags=-shared -ldflags=-shared -pkgdir=/Users/myusername/go/pkg/gomobile/pkg_android_arm std` manually. **Make sure** it is installed **successfully**.

2.Then silent `installStd` inside `init.go`.

```
go/src/golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gomobile/init.go (around Line 165-175)
// Install standard libraries for cross compilers.
start := time.Now()
//if ndkRoot != "" {
    // Ideally this would be -buildmode=c-shared.
    // https://golang.org/issue/13234.
    // androidArgs := []string{"-gcflags=-shared", "-ldflags=-shared"}
    // for _, arch := range archs {
        // env := androidEnv[arch]
        // if err := installStd(env, androidArgs...); err != nil {
            // return err
        // }
    // }
//}
```

3.Install the workaround gomobile again: `go install golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gomobile`

4.Run `gomobile init` again.